# Scala Guice how to inject configuration parameter as string?

Tags: scala, guice

I found the following code in Java explaining how to nicely inject your configuration parameter as annotated string parameters using guice.
https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions

I would like to do the same thing but in scala.
How would you do it?

And note I'm looking for a solution working with generic trait/class. Something for

```
trait Foo[T <- SomeOtherType] {}
class FooImpl[T <- SomeOtherType](val url: String) extend Foo[T] {}
```

I looked into assisted injection but can't figure it out for my issue.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The only way I see how to do this is using Assisted Injection with a factory trait for Foo and FooImpl AND providing my own impl of the factory. But this imply binding my factory using the toInstance(new FooFactory([my string params]). And still I'm not sure it would work with generic...

The annotation solution in Java looks cleaner and simpler. But can't figure it out for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do it in Scala exactly as you would do it in Java. First, define an annotation:

```
/**
 * Annotates the URL of the foo server.
 */
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@BindingAnnotation
public @interface FooServerAddress {}
```

Note that this is Java code; you cannot define runtime annotations in Scala.

Then you bind a constant annotated with this annotation:

```
bindConstant().annotatedWith(classOf[FooServerAddress])
```

And finally, you inject it:

```
class FooImpl[T] @Inject() (@FooServerAddress val url: String) extends Foo[T] {}
```

Genericity of the target class doesn't really matter here.

Also, if you use Guice with Scala, consider using [scala-guice](https://github.com/codingwell/scala-guice); among everything else, it allows you to omit these clunky `classOf`s.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried it and it works. But, to satisfy my curiosity here, what if I want to write this annotation interface in pure scala? Is it possible?

Comment: No, as I said, it is not possible to define annotations with runtime retention in Scala.